# Closed form for the finite sum $\sum_{r=1}^n \frac{1}{r^2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

> What will be the value of 
>   $$\sum_{r=1}^n \frac{1}{r^2}$$
>   in terms of **finite** $n$?

I tried to solve it using $V_n$ method but couldn't get how to convert this series in telscopic series.

Please anyone help me to solve it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does the sum of inverse squares equal $\pi^2/6$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1954692/why-does-the-sum-of-inverse-squares-equal-pi2-6)

Comment: The series is well-known to converge. But there is no simple expression for its partial sums. Some convergent series (like $1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2^2}+\dots$) have simple expressions for the partial sums, but most don't.

Comment: The question is inconsistent in its current form. A series is by definition the limit of the partial sums of a sequence. Thus, by referring to a "series", you seem to imply that you're interested in the limit of the partial sums (hence the above suggestion of a duplicate), whereas the rest of the question seems to suggest that you're actually interested in the partial sums themselves, not just the limit. Please clarify.

Comment: Yes i am interested in partial sums not limit.

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Sum%5B1%2Fr%5E2%2C%7Br%2C1%2Cn%7D%5D

This sum defines a generalised harmonic number, and can be written in terms of the first derivative of the digamma function (sometimes called trigamma).

Answer (score 3):

Using the generalized harmonic numbers$$S_n=\sum_{i=1}^n \frac 1 {i^2}=H_n^{(2)}$$ If $n$ is large, we can use the expansion
$$S_n=\frac{\pi ^2}{6}-\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{2 n^2}-\frac{1}{6 n^3}+\frac{1}{2
   n^4}-\frac{29}{30 n^5}+\frac{3}{2 n^6}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^7}\right)$$ For example, 
$$S_{10}=\frac{1968329}{1270080}\approx 1.54977$$ while the above truncated series gives
$$S_{10} \sim \frac{\pi ^2}{6}-\frac{570749}{6000000}\approx 1.54981$$

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit backwards, but might help you work out what is required:

If we can write
$$
\sum_{r=1}^n \frac{1}{r^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{6} - \psi^{(1)}(n+1) = H^{(2)}_n
$$
we could plausibly guess that this involves
$$
\sum_{r=1}^\infty \frac{1}{r^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{6}
$$
where then all of the higher terms are subtracted off, according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigamma_function)
$$
\psi^{(1)}(n+1) = \sum_{r=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(n+1+r)^2}
$$
which might be the "telescoping" you were referring to?