# Convergence of series $\sum_{n \geq 1} {\frac{1^2+2^2+ \cdots + n^2}{n^4}}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

In the study of the following series
$$
\sum_{n \geq 1} {\frac{1^2+2^2+ \cdots + n^2}{n^p}}
$$
it is not hard to prove that it diverges for $p \leq 3$, since the sequence itself does not converge to 0. You can also conclude that the series converges for $p > 4$ by comparison with Riemann series. Raabe's test yields that the series diverges for p between 3 and 4. However it does not give any information for the case $p=4$.

Comment: Notice that $1^2 + \ldots + n^2 \sim O(n^3)$. Hence $a_n \sim n^{3 - p}$. The same way (for the $p = 4$) you can bound the sequence with constant and harmonic series.

Comment: Thanks @openspace for the prompt response. However I'm not familiar with big O and cannot follow your argument.

Comment: If you're familiar with the comparison test, it's also useful.

Comment: Asymptotically, in the case $p=4$ , the series is $C/n$ for some constant $C$ , hence divergent.

Comment: Make a comparison test...

Comment: @BobDobbs I've done that but I'm stuck for what to compare it against in the case p=4. I'm also not allowed to use asymptotically equivalent series, I must explicitly give the series I compare it against.

Comment: It would be better to represent the numerator as $\sum_{j=1}^n j^2$

Comment: Nice question.......+1

Comment: To help looking it up: It's called the Landau Big-O (and Little-o).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For $p=4$ each term is $\frac {n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6n^4} \gt \frac 1{3n}$  The sum of these is bounded below by $\frac 13$ of the harmonic series, so the sum diverges.

Answer (score 5):

We do not need to apply the explicit formula for $1^2+2^2+\ldots +n^2.$ Instead observe that
$$n^3-(n-1)^3=3n^2-3n+1\ge 3n^2$$
Hence $$1^2+2^2+\ldots +n^2\ge {1\over 3}\left ([1^3-0^3]+[2^3-1^3]+\ldots +[n^3-(n-1)^3]\right ]={1\over 3}n^3$$
Hence the $n$th term of the series for $p=4$ is greater or equal $\displaystyle{1\over 3n}.$

Another approach is to apply the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality $$(1+2+\ldots +n)^2\le (1^2+2^2+\ldots +n^2)n$$ hence $$1^2+2^2+\ldots +n^2\ge {1\over n}{n^2(n+1)^2\over 4}\ge {n^3\over 4}$$

Comment: That's very creative! @RysRyszard Szwarc possible mistake in last inequality when squaring the formula for the sum of consecutive integers, should be a 4 in the denominator (?)

Comment: @ ChristmasTree Thanks. Corrected

Comment: +1. We can also let $n'=n/2$  when $n$ is even, and $n'=(n+1)/2$ when $n$ is odd. Then $\sum_{j=1}^n j^2\ge \sum_{j=n'}^n j^2\ge \sum_{j=n'}^n(n')^2=(n-n'+1)(n')^2>(n/2)(n')^2\ge (n/2)^3.$

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Thanks for upvoting. I also thought about that way, but I do not like to deal with cases. Your way with introducing $n'$ is cute.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet I got an idea how to reduce to the case of even $n$: $$4(1^2+2^2+\ldots +n^2)\ge 1^2+2^2+\ldots +(2n)^2$$

Answer (score 2):

We know that $\displaystyle \sum _{i=1}^{n} i^{2} \ =\ \frac{n( n+1)( 2n+1)}{6}$
So $\displaystyle \frac{\sum _{i=1}^{n} i^{2}}{n^{p}} \ =\ \frac{( n+1)( 2n+1)}{6n^{p-1}}$
Now if we take the limit $\displaystyle n\rightarrow \infty $ and apply L'Hospital's Rule, we can see that
$\displaystyle \frac{4n+3}{6( p-1) n^{p-2}} \ =\ \frac{4}{6( p-1)( p-2) n^{p-3}}$

Edit: As correctly pointed out in the comments, this series diverges for $p = 4$ and later on converges for $p = 5$ (the famous Basel problem).

This is because when $p = 4$, each term effectively becomes of the form $\frac 1n$ and this we know to be diverging. On the other hand for $p = 5$ it becomes $\frac 1{n^2}$.

Comment: For $p=4$ we can bound the terms from below by $\frac 1{3n}$, the sum of which diverges as the harmonic series.

Comment: The sequence converging to 0 is necessary but not sufficient for saying a series converges, so I think this answer is wrong

Comment: @ChristmasTree Hi there, I realized just now that each term of the sequence was the term shown, and I forgot completely, the part that this term was supposed to be further added. I'll correct my answer.

Comment: @mrtechtroid Thanks for your time. I didn't know the case for p=5 was well known, can you give any references on that?

Comment: Hi there, here's a question asking the same: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1954692/why-does-the-sum-of-inverse-squares-equal-pi2-6..... We generally prove this using Fourier Series

Comment: Here's the Wiki Article explaining in depth about the same: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem